# Why can't I use the Onload event to call the Servlet

Tags: jsp

I want to trigger the Servlet with onload event at the front end, and then get the result set through SQL query statement in the Servlet, store the result set in the JavaBean, and display it on the front page after forwarding

I used tomcat version 9.0, MySql version 8.0, and the latest version of Eclipse

```
< html > <head > </head>
 <body>
  < head > 
  <script type="text/javascript ">
function f() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "DCommodityServlet ",
        //servlet文件的名称
        type: "post ",
        success: function(e) {
            alert("servlet调用成功！");
        }
    });

} < /script>
</head > <body onload = "f()" >

request.setCharacterEncoding("utf - 8 ");
String user = "root ";
String password = "123456 ";
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
Connection con = null;
DCommodity DCommodityBean = null;
DCommodityBean = new DCommodity();
session.setAttribute("DCommodityBean ", DCommodityBean);
String uri = "jdbc: mysql: //localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(uri, user, password);
    Statement sql = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM commodity ");
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    String[] columnName = new String[columnCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < columnName.length; i++) {
        columnName[i] = metaData.getColumnName(i + 1);
    }
    DCommodityBean.setColumnName(columnName);
    rs.last();
    int rowNumber = rs.getRow();
    String[][] tableRecord = DCommodityBean.getTableRecord();
    tableRecord = new String[rowNumber][columnCount];
    rs.beforeFirst();
    int i = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        for (int k = 0; k < columnCount; k++) tableRecord[i][k] = rs.getString(k + 1);
        i++;
    }
    DCommodityBean.setTableRecord(tableRecord);
    con.close();
    request.getRequestDispatcher("DCommodity.jsp").forward(request, response);
} catch(SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} < /script>
 </body > </html>/
```

Expectation: I want the result set that is quested from the database after invoking the Servlet and stored in the javabeans for display in the interface
Actual result: I get a JavaBean with no result

Comment: You're trying to put servlet code into the client. It doesn't work that way. All that Java code belongs in the servlet. All you have to do to invoke it is execute an HTTP POST.

Comment: I did not explain that the Servlet code was copied directly from the Servlet. I have solved this problem, thank you